# how to make a div draggable and droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

One thing left in my project was to make the two divs draggable and droppable simultaneously. Now I have the working code of divs that can be dragged and dropped but for example I can drag a div from target area and drop it on users area but I cant seem to figure out a way to drag those divs from users and assign to different users.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dragable").draggable({
        cancel: "a.ui-icon",
        revert: true,
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move",
        revertDuration: 0
    });

    $('.droppable').droppable({
        accept: ".dragable",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            // clone item to retain in original "list"
            var $item = ui.draggable.clone();
            $(this).addClass('has-drop').append($item);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/coder880/TpbZk/31/

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have updated your fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/TpbZk/33/

Comment: when you say "assign", do you mean to move the divs instead of copying them?

Comment: @Gavriel i want to drag the div(clone of the div) from target and drop it on user(single or multiple) and then if user wants he can drag a div from user1 and drop it on user 2 or 3 or 4 or anyother and vicerversa.

Comment: no no just the clone of the div should be assigned to different user

Comment: I understand that you clone from the target area to a user, but you also want to clone from user1 to user2, and not move it from user1 to user2. Right?

Comment: @hetasbo, man its working good but there are two problems here.
1) The target div should only drop the clone of it, it shouldn't disappear from the target column.
2)In your fiddle i'm able to drop only one div at a particular user i want to drop multiple divs also

Comment: @Gavriel, i'm sorry if i'm not so clear, when i drag from a user to a user than it should be moved and when i drag from target then it should be cloned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because once the item is dragged/dropped it is then cloned. This clone does not have the `draggable()` plugin instantiated on it. You need to call `draggable()` on the `$item` again. Try this:

```
var draggableOptions = {
    cancel: "a.ui-icon",
    revert: true,
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    revertDuration: 0
}

$(".dragable").draggable(draggableOptions);

$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: ".dragable",
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $item = ui.draggable.clone();
        $item.draggable(draggableOptions);
        $(this).addClass('has-drop').append($item);
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TpbZk/32/)

> it should only be cloned when its from target otherwise it should move it.

To achieve this you need to remove the `helper: 'clone'` option in the cloned draggable element and maintain a flag on the element to determine whether it is a brand new clone or has been dragged previously and moved again. To do this you could use a class, something like this:

```
$(".dragable").draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon",
    revert: true,
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    revertDuration: 0
});

$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: ".dragable",
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $item = $(ui.draggable)
        if (!$item.hasClass('clone')) {
            $item = $item.clone().addClass('clone');
            $item.draggable({
                cancel: "a.ui-icon",
                revert: true,
                cursor: "move",
                revertDuration: 0
            });
        }
        $(this).addClass('has-drop').append($item);
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TpbZk/35/)

Comment: ok thats the best, one thing, when i drag from users it should not be cloned. how could i do this? it should only be cloned when its from target otherwise it should move it.

Comment: He wants to move the divs from user to user, this is just half solution

Comment: i removed the helper clone option form $item.draggable($mycustomvariable) but its not working fine.

Comment: To achieve that you need to change the logic so that you can recognise which element is a brand new clone and which has been dropped before and moved again. See my update for more detail.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.